# change parent state from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to change the parent state from the child

```
export const ParentComponent=()=>{

 const [ resendCodeStatus ,setResendCodeStatus ] = useState(false)

 const callback=()=>{

   setResendCodeStatus(!resendCodeStatus)

 }

 return (

   < Timer  callback={callback} />

 )
}
```

but I can access the callback function just once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
export const ParentComponent=()=>{

const [ resendCodeStatus ,setResendCodeStatus ] = useState(false)
const callbackFunction=()=>{
setResendCodeStatus((status) => !status)
}
return (
<Timer callbackFunction={callbackFunction} />
) }
```